# syntax for calling method of an object inside an object

Tags: php, oop, syntax

Probably a stupid question, but my IDE (PHPStorm) and I are having a bit of a disagreement...

```
class Item_Backpack {
    public function Empty() {
        // dump contents
    }

    public function insertThing($thing) {
        // insert thing into backpack
    }
}

class Student {
    private $_Backpack; // is a class, can contain other objects

    function __construct() {
        $this->_Backpack = new Item_Backpack;
    }

    public function emptyBackpack() {
        $this->_Backpack->Empty(); // IDE says method undefined
                                   // and cannot give method/property hints
                                   // for this object :-3
    }
}
```

The `Item_Backpack` class has the method `public function Empty()` which ... *empties the backpack!*

Is my syntax correct here?

Comment: The only thing wrong is that your constructor is missing a `function` keyword. I'm surprised PhpStorm didn't choke on that instead, unless you simply missed it out while manually typing here.

Comment: that's a typo here, I didn't cut and paste

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's having problems because empty() is a reserved function name in PHP - you just need to rename the function to something else, ie. emptyContents()

Comment: +1 Yep, my Netbeans 7 got happy once I changed the method name from `Empty()` to something else.